# extract rich text field from PDF using vb to MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I'm looping through files and I have a fillable PDF form that I am extracting data from.  Everything works except when I extract from a rich text field.  I get the data, but it looses its formatting.

My code is below. For example, 'General_Match_Comments' is my rich text field in the PDF, but when it comes into the Access Database, it is missing the formatting such as multi-line

```
Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp 
Dim theForm As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc 
Dim jso As Object 
Dim oFSO As Object 
Dim oFolder As Object 
Dim oFile As Object 

Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App") 
Set theForm = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc") 
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(varfolder)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        theForm.Open (oFile)
        Set jso = theForm.GetJSObject
    
        Dim rstblEvalHeader As Recordset
        Set rstblEvalHeader = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="tblEvalHeader", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
        With rstblEvalHeader
            .AddNew
                ' get the information from the form fields Text1 and Text2
                !Referee = jso.getField("Referee").Value
                !EvalDate_af_date = jso.getField("EvalDate_af_date").Value
                !Position = jso.getField("R1R2").Value
                !Event_Site = jso.getField("Event_Site").Value
                !Partner = jso.getField("Partner").Value
                !Level_of_Play = jso.getField("Level_of_Play").Value
                !Time_Court = jso.getField("Time_Court").Value
                !Teams = jso.getField("Teams").Value
                !Observer = jso.getField("Observer").Value
                !Match_Scores = jso.getField("Match_Scores").Value
                !Match_Difficulty = jso.getField("Match_Difficulty").Value
                !General_Match_Comments = jso.getField("General_Match_Comments").Value
                !Result = jso.getField("Result").Value
                strGUID = !ID
                strGUID = Replace(Replace(strGUID, "{guid ", ""), "}}", "}")
                !SID = strGUID
            .Update
            
        End With
        theForm.Close
    Next oFile
```

Comment: What is the type of theForm? Which library is it defined in and is there any documentation?

Comment: Only solutions I can find involve Word. Issue is same, how to retain RTF. Maybe can adapt suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399312/how-to-insert-rtf-from-word-doc-into-access-table-field